# Is my understanding how of a secure connection is made using PKI correct?

Tags: encryption, tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure

My understanding as as follows:

**Client** requests a secure connection with a Website's Server

**Server** provides a certificate with the address of the server and public key of the server encrypted with a Certificate Authority's (CA's) private key.

**Client** then decrypts that certificate with the public key of the CA which is packed with the OS/browser and verifies it is an authentic certificate from the CA which has not been decommissioned. The client now knows we can trust the server.

**Client** then provides their public key encrypted with the server's public key.

The two can now communicate securely with the data sent from the **client** being encrypted with the **public key of the server** and decrypted by the **server** with the **private key of the server** and with the data sent from the **server** being encrypted with the **public key of the client** and decrypted by the **client** with the **private key of the client**.

Since the private keys are kept private and not distributed even if some malicious agent gets hold of the encrypted data traffic since it was encrypted with the public key they cannot decrypt any of it unless they have somehow got hold of one of the private keys.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work)

Comment: Yes, that explains it really well, thanks!

Comment: I do have one question, so the server sends the certificate with the server public key in it, the client decrypts it with the CA's public key and then some step happens where the client communicates back to the server with a message encrypted with the server's public key that the connection is verified and then they both generate a symmetric key for further encrypted communication, how do they both generate the same key? Does the client send some sort of key for the seed generation encrypted with the server's public key?